# Eclipse RAP: How to access deployed application

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-rap

I created a helloworld eclipse RAP  project and run it eclipse itself.It is working fine.
After that I exported the RAP project to war file by using the eclipse war product configuration.
It created the war file.I deployed the war file in tomcat. After that when I try to access
the war deployed helloworld application, I am getting status 404 error.

http://127.0.0.1:8080/helloworld

I searched in internet and checked for troubleshooting and they mentioned to check in web.xml
all the entries are available or not. I confirmed it is available. Also I checked application structure.
It is fine as it is suggested. Could any one help me how to access the deployed application in tomcat?
Or is there any other server I can use in order to make it work quickly?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that the war file is named `helloworld.war` and http://127.0.0.1:8080/helloworld is the URL of your application.

If your entrypoint is not registered at the root path, you have to add the entrypoint name to the URL, e.g. http://127.0.0.1:8080/helloworld/entrypoint.

Alternatively, you can register the application at the root path in your ApplicationConfiguration:

```
application.addEntryPoint("/", YourEntryPoint.class, properties);
```

Then you should be able to access it at http://127.0.0.1:8080/helloworld.

**Update:**

If you use extension points, configure the path in your entrypoint extension, for example:

```
<extension
    point="org.eclipse.rap.ui.entrypoint">
  <entrypoint
      class="example.MyEntrypoint"
      path="/" />
</extension>
```

Comment: Hi @ralfstx  It is a rap  application. Not a rwt application. So do I need to configure the entrypoint? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Then you probably have an extension in your plugin.xml to configure the entrypoint. Change the path attribute to "/", e.g.: `<entrypoint class="example.MyEntrypoint" path="/" />`.

Comment: I have Activator,Application,ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor,Perspective all are included in that. And I have written LoginDialog inside the ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor. How to make a call if I use EntryPoint?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your last question. In order to help you, let me ask you some questions in order to understand your case better: 1. Does your application have a `plugin.xml`? 2. Can you find the *entrypoint* extension in there (see code example above)? 3. What is the *path* attribute? 4. What is the name of your war file? 5. Which RAP version are you using?

Comment: 1,Yes.2. Yes.3. The path is /mail. 4. hellorap.war 5. rap2.3  In the extensionpoint  is declared as below.<extension
         id="mailapp.entrypoints"
         point="org.eclipse.rap.ui.entrypoint">
      <entrypoint
            path="/mail"
            applicationId="rapentrypoint.mailapp"
            id="mailapp.entrypoint">
      </entrypoint>
   </extension>

Comment: In this case, you should be able to access your application at  http://127.0.0.1:8080/helloworld/mail. If you change the path to `<entrypoint path="/"`, then  http://127.0.0.1:8080/helloworld/ should work.